# How to keep div hidden after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've a simple show and hide div.

The div automatically loads on loading the page and then you can close the div by clicking close.

Once you refresh the page the div shows up again, how do I code it to once closed, to not open again for say a month.

Thanks in advance.

Ben

This is the code I have so far;

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://innosite.s3.amazonaws.com/cookie/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
 // hides the slickbox as soon as the DOM is ready
  $('#slickbox').show();
 // shows the slickbox on clicking the noted link  
  $('#slick-show').click(function() {
    $('#slickbox').show('slow');
    return false;
  });
 // hides the slickbox on clicking the noted link  
  $('#slick-hide').click(function() {
    $('#slickbox').hide('fast');
    return false;
  });

 // toggles the slickbox on clicking the noted link  
  $('#slick-toggle').click(function() {
    $('#slickbox').toggle(400);
    return false;
  });
});

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}


//user closes your box
createCookie('mybox',1,30);

//check if the box should be hidden
if (readCookie('mybox')) 
    $('#slickbox').hide();
</script>
```

Comment: I'd google something along the lines of "javascript+cookie+splash screen"

Comment: I'd just use `localStorage` instead of cookies. The API is much easier and simpler and effective. There are back-compat jQuery plugins that fallback from localStorage to cookies if the user is using an old version of IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always just use local storage :

```
$(function() {

    if (localStorage) { //if local storage
        if (!localStorage.getItem('visited')) { // if not site is visited before
            $('#slickbox').show(); //show element
        }
    } else { //if not local storage use cookies or just show element in old browsers
        $('#slickbox').show();
    }

    // shows the slickbox on clicking the noted link  
    $('#slick-show').click(function() {
        $('#slickbox').show('slow');
        return false;
    });
    // hides the slickbox on clicking the noted link  
    $('#slick-hide').click(function() {
        $('#slickbox').hide('fast');
        localStorage.setItem('visited', true); //set flag, site now visited and element hidden
        return false;
    });

    // toggles the slickbox on clicking the noted link  
    $('#slick-toggle').click(function() {
        $('#slickbox').toggle(400);
        return false;
    });
});​
```

Comment: I was just about to use localstorage rather than cookies! Just came across it! :)

Comment: Yepp, only IE7 -> below and some other really old browsers does not have support, so the number of users that does not have support for local storage is tiny, so I would just show or hide the element as a default state for anyone with a crappy browser and not really care to much about if it's annoying to those users, as long the site works, as this affects maybe tops 1% og users. And it's so much easier to deal with compared to cookies.

Comment: I've used that code in place of the other code and now the div isn't showing up at all.

Comment: That's because you've already visited the site? If you're using chrome open the console (F12), click resources and find local storage, now find the "visited" entry (should be set to true) and delete it to show the element again.

Comment: I've cleared the browsers cache using "Clear Browsing Data", still nothing displays.

Comment: That does'nt help, you'll need to delete the local storage entry.

Comment: Here's a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CBAvj/), it will show a red box on the first visit only, and not at all on subsequent visits, at least until the local storage entry is deleted.

Comment: There is no entry. I am receiving this error tho.   

// toggles the slickbox on clicking the noted link  
    $('#slick-toggle').click(function() {
        $('#slickbox').toggle(400);
        return false;
    });
});​
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
</script>

Comment: Ok, that's all fixed now! :) Thanks alot! Just wondering, rather than have the box automatically disappear when they've visited and refreshed or click on another page, how can I make it disappear when they click hide? & if they don't, I'd like it to remain visible.

Comment: Just do the local storage stuff in the click handler where you hide the element, that way it will only run if they click the hide button.

Comment: I have tried that but once it disappears, it then re-appears. This is the code I have, http://pastebin.com/VBk24xK0

Answer (score 1):

Here is a reference. With that tiny code its, probably easier just to start over.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: What do you mean, some variable?

Comment: like a cookie or some parameter in the url.

Comment: I know that, I'm trying to set a cookie, using that code. Everything I've tried, doesn't work.

Comment: I must be crazy, I didn't see that you had any code at first. :( Finally, I scrolled

Answer (score 1):

There was a comment "use a cookie" and then it disappeared, even though it fits the bill perfectly: you can set and read it on the client side. Just ignore it on the server. There's even a jQuery plugin.

Comment: I've decided to use localstorage now! :)