# problem making localStorage to work with my hide/show function

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a function that allows the user to click on a button to push a div to the side. The user can then hit the same button again to push the div back to its originally place.

However if the user decides to push the div away and then refreshes the page, the div will then be back to its originally place. This is my problem. I want the div to stay pushed away even after the page is refreshed.

I then searched through stackoverflow to see if this problem already had an answer, and my closest finding was this post: [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062836/how-to-keep-div-hidden-after-page-refresh/12063002#12063002)

From that post it looks like localStorage is the solution to my problem, however I tried to my best abilities to implement localStorage to my script, but without any luck. 
If the user pushes the div and then refreshes the page, the div is back to its originally place.

Here is my script with my localStorage attempt.

```
$(function() {

if (localStorage) { //if local storage

        if (!localStorage.getItem('visited')) { // if not site is visited before
          alert("localStorage is working");

        }
    } else { //if not local storage use cookies or just show element in old browsers
      alert("localStorage is working");

    }


$('#hide').click(function(){
    if($('#profile-section').attr("trigger")==="0"){
        $('#profile-section').animate({"left":"80%"},700);
        $('#profile-section').attr("trigger","1");
        localStorage.setItem('visited', true); //set flag, site now visited and element hidden


    }
    else{
        $('#profile-section').animate({"left":"95%"},700);
        $('#profile-section').attr("trigger","0");
        localStorage.setItem('visited', false); //set flag, site now visited and element hidden

    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try

```
if (localStorage.getItem('visited') === 'true') { // if not site is visited before
          alert("localStorage is working");
}
```

else your expression always returns a `false`.

EDIT

replace

```
  if (!localStorage.getItem('visited')) { // if not site is visited before
          alert("localStorage is working");

        }
```

with

```
if (localStorage.getItem('visited') === 'true') { // if not site is visited before
          alert("localStorage is working");
}
```

or the answer above with `JSON.parse`.

Comment: can you `console.log` the value of localStorage after `if (localStorage) { //if local storage`

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you. Did you want me to insert your code instead of: if (localStorage) { //if local storage

        if (!localStorage.getItem('visited')) { // if not site is visited before
          alert("localStorage is working");

        }

Comment: I don't know why it did not work the first time, maybe a typo..as I did exactly what you wrote in your EDIT. But now it works! I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Change to:

```
if (localStorage) { //if local storage

    if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('visited'))) {
      alert("localStorage is working");
    }
} else { //if not local storage use cookies or just show element in old browsers
  alert("localStorage is working");
}
```

Comment: I tested this and it appears that setting a `boolean` value in localstorage turns it into `string`. Then the `if` would evaluate to `true` every time because `if ('false')` and `if ('true')` are both passing as true.

Comment: @VladimirBogomolov True, edited to parse the response from `localStorage`.